# MongoDB Atlas Error while performing transaction on multiple collections (code 8000)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to perform a transaction on a Mongo DB Atlas M0 instance from Mongo DB Node JS driver (as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-and-retryable-writes)) and I'm getting the following error:

```
code:8000
codeName:"AtlasError"
errmsg:"internal atlas error checking things: Failure getting dbStats: read tcp 192.168.254.78:50064->192.168.254.78:27000: i/o timeout"
message:"internal atlas error checking things: Failure getting dbStats: read tcp 192.168.254.78:50064->192.168.254.78:27000: i/o timeout"
name:"MongoError"
```

I've been searching for a while now and can't find any clue on how to solve this.

**Aditional information:**

- The error is thrown after adding the second operation to the
  transaction.
- If I remove all the other operations and leave only one (doesn't
  matter which) it works fine.
- If I change the order of the operations (to any order) the error is
  still on adding the second operation.
- If the operations are all performed to the same db and collection, it works fine

**My code:**

```
async function connect () {

if (dbClient !== null && dbClient.isConnected()) {
    console.log('Reusing db connection => ' + JSON.stringify(dbClient));
  } else {
      console.log('Connecting to database');
      dbClient = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
      console.log('Successfully connected to database');
  }
}

async function insertDocuments(document1, document2, document3) {

  try {
    await connect();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }

  let session = dbClient.startSession();

  session.startTransaction({
    readConcern: { level: 'snapshot' },
    writeConcern: { w: 'majority' }
  });

  const collection1 = dbClient.db('mydbname').collection('collection1');
  const collection2 = dbClient.db('mydbname').collection('collection2');
  const collection3 = dbClient.db('mydbname').collection('collection3');
  const logsCollection = dbClient.db('mydbname').collection('logs');

  await collection1.replaceOne(
    { _id: document1._id },
    document1,
    {
      upsert: true,
      session
    }
  );
  await collection2.replaceOne(
    { _id: document2._id },
    document2,
    {
      upsert: true,
      session
    }
  );
  await collection3.replaceOne(
    { _id: document3._id },
    document3,
    {
      upsert: true,
      session
    }
  );
  await logsCollection.updateOne(
    { _id: document1._id },
    { $unset: { estoque: '' } },
    { session }
  );

  try {
    await commitWithRetry(session);
  } catch (error) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
    throw error;
  }
}

async function commitWithRetry(session) {
  try {
    await session.commitTransaction();
    console.log('Transação gravada com sucesso');
  } catch (error) {
    if (
      error.errorLabels &&
      error.errorLabels.indexOf('UnknownTransactionCommitResult') >= 0
    ) {
      console.log('Transação não realizada, tentando novamente ...');
      await commitWithRetry(session);
    } else {
      console.log('Erro ao gravar no banco de dados ...');
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *" ... Atlas M0 instance ..."* - So do you mean there is only **one** node? I suppose "technically" even with one node it should still be registered as a replica set. Probably depends on how you are actually connecting to this though, and your connection string is missing from the sample code. If you just copy the string that should be provided then it "should" be fine. But I suspect you omitted the `replicaSet` parts.

Comment: @NeilLunn sorry for the delay. This is my connection string: 'mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD@dev-qa-nftzq.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true'. What do you mean by "But I suspect you omitted the replicaSet parts."? How to include it?

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem, it appears to be related to accessing multiple collections. I'd already tested the code on a local replSet with no errors, so it might be an Atlas problem rather than a MongoDB problem. On the other hand, that local replSet only had 1 node. Have you gotten around to testing it with an M10 or better cluster?

Comment: @DrBearhands I didn't test it on any instance other than M0. As you said, it seems to be related to accessing multiple collections. I've tested the same operations over a single collection and it worked fine.

Comment: @GCSDC Well, I made a support ticket. Will let you know how that turns out.

Comment: Any news on the issue? Having the same problem. Was thinking on opening a support ticket myself but figured that if you already solved it it-ll be easier.

Comment: @DrBearhands did you get any return on the ticket?

Comment: @GCSDC Not yet.

Comment: I reported this problem to Atlas too, they said their engineers are currently working on it, no timeframe. Meanwhile I'm running on an M10 which works fine but far too expensive for development purposes.

Comment: @ChristiaanMaks thanks! Hope they fix that soon, as in most cases it is not suitable to have a M10 cluster for a development or even a quality/staging environment. For some companies or apps, it may not be required even for a production environment.

Comment: @GCSDC Just received this email:

This is a quick update to let you know that the reported issue in this case should be addressed in MongoDB 4.0.5, which we are expecting to have available in MongoDB Atlas in January 2019.

We will keep this ticket open in **Waiting for Development** state, and will provide a further update when our shared tiers (M0, M2, M5) have been upgraded to 4.0.5.

Comment: @DrBearhands good news! Thanks for the update!

Comment: @GCSDC looks like they updated the clusters. For me though, this shows their technology isn't mature enough yet for the guarantees I expect in ACID transactions, so I've returned to relational DBs. Just something worth considering.

Comment: I just received a message from Mongo support that they upgraded to 4.0.5 on the shared tier and that the issue should be resolved. I can't test it myself currently since I've upgraded to M10.

Comment: Tested the same code from my question with an M0 instance and it worked. Should I post an answer with this? Should this question be closed?

Comment: I came across this error, and turned out my Mongo Atlas authentication was wrong. I had copied the mongo url link wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, according to MongoDB team this issue has been solved on version 4.0.5

I've tested the same code posted on my question and it now works fine.

For anyone facing the same issue, make sure to be using a version equal to or higher than 4.0.5.

Comment: I am on mongodb Atlas `Version 4.0.8` and still having it

Comment: @matcheek I've been using the code I posted, also with version 4.0.8 and it works fine. Suggest you to double check your code, and if you still have an issue, open a ticket to mongodb team or raise a new question on SO.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue and could not solve it. I ended up creating a new cluster on Azure (instead of AWS) and it seems to be working fine.

Not sure if this is an issue with their implementation on AWS or case by case mis-configuration

**Update**: The same error is now happening on the new cluster. I raised a ticket and got the following response;

> This has been determined to be a bug currently affecting the M0 free cluster and shared tiers of Atlas (M2 and M5). We have opened an internal bug report to address this. While the internal development queue for our Cloud products is not publicly visible, we are tracking the work required to make multi-document transactions work on Atlas free tier clusters.

They said the same thing as the other answer. Please use M10. However, M10 is about $60/m which is not quite a resolution by any means. It also completely invalidates the main selling point of them saying M0 now includes MongoDb 4.0

Comment: Thanks Michael! Do you have a ticket number or any reference to keep track of the issue?

Comment: They've mentioned their internal development queue is hidden, so I don't think there will be much for you to see. Personal support tickets are not visible to the public so I can't share it, but there's not a lot of info on that either.

Answer (score 3):

i solved this proplem by going to the NetWork Access in my Database that in mongo db Cloub and and deleted the old IP Address and put a new IP Address by clicking add IP Address And Chose this current ID Address

Comment: Can you post the error you saw so that readers can validate that you had the same error message?

Comment: Also, what version are you on? This looks to be an issue from an earlier version.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. The Support Department said that since I was using Mongoose, they couldn't help. However, they were kind enough to gift me 10$ in credit so I could test it out with a higher tier.

That was the issue, as soon as I upgraded to M10 tier (the next one after M0) transactions started working as intended. Your code is very similar as mine, only that I was creating one document and updating 2 others at the same time. Just like in your case, the first one went through (no matter the order) and the next just timed out with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1  download https://robomongo.org/download

- when you have the Studio 3T trial Licence interface go to Quick Start

Step 2: create a new connection. Make sure port is `localhost:27017` and db name your project name

Step 3: you will see a blue to connect, Note leave as default.

- You will receive an initial error because DB is not installed on terminal.

Go to : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

On terminal project folder in macOS.

1. `brew tap mongodb/brew`
2. `brew install mongodb-community@4.2`
3. `mongo`. 
   if you get ==> `` Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community) ``, then hopefully there is no error on terminal.

Last step: go back to interface and click blue button DB will automatically connect.

```
// .env file on project root folder
MONGO_URI='mongodb://localhost:27017/projectname'
```

Connection code below :

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log('DB Connected'));

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(`DB connection error: ${err.message}`);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello from the other side');
});
```

Comment: Please **format** your post (text & code) appropriately

Comment: Thanks will do so next time

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error, and I spent hours trying to debug it. Then I deleted the old cluster that had AWS and made a new one with Google Cloud, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue, just check your connection URI. I had wrong password.

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced this type error . as conclusion set your cluster password without special characters like '@/#'.or use autogenerated password .it worked to me

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by creating a database with atlas on MongoDb Site.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to "https://www.mongodb.com/" and Sign in.
2. Click on "Network Access" just below "Security" section, on the left side of your screen.
3. Click on "Delete" button of your current IP Address.
4. Then, click on "ADD IP ADDRESS". On right side of your screen. That will show you a popup box.
5. Click on "ADD CURRENT IP ADDRESS" and confirm.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same problem, in my situation I've used a Temporary user for a week and I forget about it. So maybe it helps someone :)