# Problem when saving data in mongo DB using node.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i'm trying to register a user in node.js using mongo DB us database but i have an irror i don't know where what is due to this error here is my code

```
  const userModal=require('../models/user.model');
    
    module.exports.signUp = async(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
        const {pseudo, email, password} = req.body
    
        try{
            const user = await userModal.create({pseudo,email,password});
            res.status(201).json({ user: user._id});
        }
      catch(err){
          res.status(200).send({ err })
      }
    
    }
```

i have this error in postman

```
{
    "err": {
        "ok": 0,
        "code": 8000,
        "codeName": "AtlasError",
        "name": "MongoError"
    }
}
```

but in may console i really have date data each time in submit the postman button

```
{ pseudo: 'test', email: 'test@gmail.com', password: 'test33' }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254164/mongodb-atlas-error-while-performing-transaction-on-multiple-collections-code-8

Comment: the connexion to mongo DB is ok but i can't be able to save data , i even tried to change the AWS to google Cloud and it does'nt work.